# Function works in Chrome/Safari but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

So I have a table where you can check a table row and it will get the values of each cell in that row and also display another column named `Quantity #`. The `Quantity #` column contains a `type="number"` input. After entering a number, a user will be able to refresh the page and the `Quantity #` column and the value entered into the input will both remain visible. A user can also hit a "Checkout" button and it will post that data to an email body.

That all works great in Safari and Google Chrome. However, in Firefox, if you enter a value into the input and then refresh for example, the value will no longer be in the input. Also, if you hit the Checkout button and it pastes the data to the email, it will not paste the input value either like it does in Safari/Chrome.

Why is this and what can I do to fix this problem in Firefox?

JavaScript:

```
$(function($) {
    var RowData = (function(storage, storageKey) {
        var rowData = readFromSession();
        var dataItems = ['loc', 'rp-code', 'sku', 'special-id', 'description', 'quantity', 'unit'];
        var emailDelimiters = {
            'row': '%0D%0A',
            'dataItem': '\xa0\xa0'
        };

        function readFromSession() {
            return JSON.parse(storage.getItem(storageKey) || '{}');
        }
        function writeToSession() {
            storage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(rowData));
        }
        function writeRow(tr) {
            var $tr = $(tr),
                id = $tr.prop('id');
            if($tr.find('.check').is(':checked')) {
                rowData[id] = {};
                for(var i=0; i<dataItems.length; i++) {
                    rowData[id][dataItems[i]] = $tr.find('.' + dataItems[i]).text();
                }
                rowData[id].quantity_num = $tr.find('.spinner').val();
            } else {
                delete rowData[id];
            }
            writeToSession();
        }
        function readRow(tr) {
            // restore tr's checkbox and spinner value from stored data
            var $tr = $(tr),
                id = $tr.prop('id'),
                row = rowData[id];
            if(row) {
                $tr.find('.check').prop('checked', true).end()
                     // .find('.spinner').spinner('value', row.quantity_num); // if using spinner widget
                     .find('.spinner').val(row.quantity_num); // if using HTML5 <input type="number">
            }
        }
        function toEmailString() {
            return $.map(rowData, function(row, id) {
                return $.map(row, window.encodeURIComponent).join(emailDelimiters.dataItem);
            }).join(emailDelimiters.row);
        }
        // selectively expose functions as methods of RowData
        return {
            'writeRow': writeRow,
            'readRow': readRow, 
            'toEmailString': toEmailString
        };
    })(window.sessionStorage, 'checkedRowData');

    $('#merchTable').on('change', '.check', function() { // on changing a table row ...
        RowData.writeRow($(this).closest('tr').get(0)); // ... set the corresponding row object in RowData and sessionStorage
    }).on('blur', '.spinner', function() { // on leaving a spinner widget
        RowData.writeRow($(this).closest('tr').get(0));
    });
    $('#checkout').on('click', function() { // on clicking the [Checkout] button
        var link = "mailto:me@example.com" + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("Order") + "&body=" + RowData.toEmailString();
        console.log(link);
        window.location.href = link;
    });

    // Call this function on completion of every pagination/search
    function restoreVisibleRows() {
        $('#merchTable tbody tr').get().forEach(RowData.readRow);
    }

    restoreVisibleRows();

});
```

JavaScript that keeps input value and quantity # column displayed on refresh:

```
$(function(){
    var showQuantityHeader = false;
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        // Iterate over the checkboxes and set their "check" values based on the session data
        var $el = $(this);
        //console.log('element id: ',$el.prop('id'),' sessionStorage[id]: ',sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')]);
        $el.prop('checked', sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] === 'true');
        if ($el.prop('checked')) {          
            //show the quantity cell in the column under header with class num
            $el.closest('tr').find('td.quantity_num').toggle(this.checked);
            showQuantityHeader = true;
            //setupSpinner(this);
            var quantity = sessionStorage['value_'+$el.prop('id')];

        }
    });

    if (showQuantityHeader) {
            $('#merchTable').find('th.num').show();
        //console.log('header with class num: ',$('#merchTable').find('th.num'));
    }

    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
        // save the individual checkbox in the session inside the `change` event, 
        // using the checkbox "id" attribute
        var $el = $(this);
        sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] = $el.is(':checked');
        console.log($el);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<section id="checkout-btn"> 
<button id="checkout" name="order">Checkout</button>
</section>

<br>

<table id="merchTable" cellspacing="5" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="sorttable_nosort"></th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Loc</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="merchRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Special ID</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Description</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Unit</th>
            <th style="display: none;" class="num">Quantity #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr id="<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>">
            <td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" id="checkid-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
            <td class="loc ui-widget-content" data-loc="<?php echo $row['Loc'] ?>"><input type="hidden"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
            <td class="rp-code ui-widget-content" align="center" data-rp-code="<?php echo $row['Rp-Code'] ?>" id="rp-code-<?php echo intval ($row['Rp-Code'])?>"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
            <td class="sku ui-widget-content" data-sku="<?php echo $row['SKU'] ?>" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
            <td class="special-id ui-widget-content" data-special-id="<?php echo $row['Special-ID'] ?>" align="center" id="special-id-<?php echo intval ($row['Special-ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
            <td class="description ui-widget-content" data-description="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['Description']) ?>" id="description-<?php echo intval ($row['Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
            <td class="quantity ui-widget-content" data-quantity="<?php echo $row['Quantity'] ?>" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
            <td class="unit ui-widget-content" data-unit="<?php echo $row['Unit'] ?>" id="unit-<?php echo intval ($row['Unit'])?>"><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
            <td style="display: none;" class="quantity_num ui-widget-content"><input type="number" min="1" max="<?php echo $row['Quantity'];?>" step="1" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" /></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT:
[image: Console errors]

Comment: Does FireFox give any console errors?

Comment: I made an edit with a screenshot of the errors

Comment: Those are errors related to CSS. Are there any JavaScript errors?

Comment: No, not that I see

Comment: I made sure that the JS error/warning filters were on and I am not getting any errors

Comment: It is hard to tell whats wrong from the code presented. I would suggest to use the FF debugger to find out.

Comment: When there are no errors console.log is your friend to find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rataiczak24, it would appear that FF doesn't fire its `blur` event in exactly the same way as the other browsers.

Storing a row's state is currently done in response `quantity_num` inputs' `blur` events. For performance reasons, I was hoping you wouldn't need to do this, but you need to respond to the 'change' event instead of the 'blur' event. Responsiveness of the `quantity_num` input may suffer.

That should solve both reported problems.

There's some other stuff too :

With my `RowData` object in place, you shouldn't be interacting with `sessionStorage` directly (unless of course you use it for other purposes). All interactions should be via the RowData API, and all code outside of `RowData()` should neither read from nor write to `sessionStorage`.

If at any point you need confidence that a table row might need to be restored to the state stored in `sessionStorage`, then call `RowData.readRow(tr)`, or call `restoreVisibleRows()` to restore all visible rows.

If you follow my instruction "Call this function on completion of every pagination/search", and call `restoreVisibleRows();` on page load, then row restoration should not need to be addressed elsewhere.

Almost all of what's in your `$(function() { var showQuantityHeader = false; ...; ...; ...; });` above is unnecessary. The only part that's not catered for in `RowData` is `$('#merchTable').find('th.num').show();`. For that, you just need to add add a few lines to `restoreVisibleRows()`, and similarly in response to checkboxes being checked/unchecked.

So, all-in-all, the bottom part of my code suggestion should look like this :

```
$('#merchTable').on('change', '.check', function() { // on cliking a checkbox
    var $this = $(this),
        $tr = $this.closest('tr');
    $tr.find('td.quantity_num').toggle(this.checked);
    $this.closest('table').find('th.num').toggle($('input:checkbox:checked', '#merchTable tbody').length > 0);
    RowData.writeRow($tr.get(0)); // store row state
}).on('change', '.spinner', function() { // on changing the value of a "spinner" widget
    RowData.writeRow($this.closest('tr').get(0)); // store row state
});
$('#checkout').on('click', function() { // on clicking the [Checkout] button
    setTimeout(function() {
        var link = "mailto:me@example.com" + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("Order") + "&body=" + RowData.toEmailString();
        console.log(link);
        window.location.href = link;
    }, 0);
});

function restoreVisibleRows() {
    $('#merchTable tbody tr').get().forEach(RowData.readRow);
    if($('input:checkbox:checked', '#merchTable tbody').length > 0) {
        $('#merchTable').find('th.num').show();
    } else {
        $('#merchTable').find('th.num').hide();
    }
}
```

Your own `$(".check").change(function(){...})` (if it still exists) can be removed.

Comment: Hey again! Thanks for the response! It says that `$tr` is not defined at `RowData.writeRow($tr.get(0));` under the second `on change` function when I try and use the spinner to set a number for the input

Comment: Actually, it looks like I got it...you were right in that FF doesnt seem to fire off `blur` events. All i did was change the `blur` event to a `change` event and it seems to be working on chrome, safari, AND firefox now! Thanks!